# Selecting Items from Database that Matches with the string Based on Entered Characters

Tags: c#, sql, .net, datagrid

I want to select the items that matches with the entered string.It seems the query is selecting all items that contain at-least a matching letter.

***I don't want exact match ..i want to select the strings that match the starting..Like if i type 'it' i want to list all strings that starts with 'it'***

What im i doing wrong?

[image]

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr))
                        {

                            try
                            {
                                conn.Open();
                                SqlDataReader myReader = null;

                                string commandText = "SELECT itemname,rate,stock FROM mytable WHERE itemname LIKE @id";
                                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn);
                                string searchParam = String.Format("%{0}%", text_item.Text);
                                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", searchParam);
                                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
                                {
                                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                                    {
                                        sda.Fill(dt);
                                        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                            catch (Exception err)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
                            }

                        }
```

Comment: @3615 Can you please post the query as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `LIKE` but use `=`. And change your string be exact string, instead of `%text%`

```
string commandText = "SELECT itemname,rate,stock FROM mytable WHERE itemname = @id";
...
string searchParam = text_item.Text;
```

---------------------- EDITED ------------------------

After the updated question, the answer would be:

```
string searchParam = string.Format("{0}%", text_item.Text);
```

The first % is not necessary, because you don't want wildcard there.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "Like" you should use "=". Like is usually used if you want to search with wildcards.

Comment: i dont want exact match ... just find strings that matches with the entered string ..Please see update.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your query to return results starting with, change your parameter value to

```
string searchParam = String.Format("{0}%", text_item.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is running fine. 
Yes, you can use LIKE operator in the query.
Kindly debug and check what's coming in the "text_item" variable. 
Narrow your search. 
You can refer the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

to check the syntax for like operator.